# Error when trying to access frames from multithreading video capturing

Tags: multithreading, opencv, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

I am using ltbb to stream from two cameras. ltbb creates two threads(because of two cameras) for simultaneous streaming from two cameras. It makes use of concurrent queues for fetching frames. The following code snippet displays frames:

```
while (waitKey(20) != 27)
  {
    //Retrieve frames from each camera capture thread
    vector<Mat> iMats(capture_source.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < capture_source.size(); i++)
    {
      Mat frame;

      //Pop frame from queue and check if the frame is valid
      if (cam.frame_queue[i]->try_pop(frame))
      {
        //Show frame on Highgui window
        // IMats.push_back(frame);
        iMats[i] = frame;
        imshow(label[i], frame);
      }

    } // end of for - loop

    int x = opencv_tri(iMats);
  }
```

**The problem is** when I am doing `iMats[i] = frame` and pass it to other function, It's giving me an error. **It works fine when I comment iMats and stop calling opencv_tri(iMats)**.

Error: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

**Link to opencv_tri:** [opencv_tri.cpp](http://txt.do/dlfnm)

Can anyone please explain and help me to fix this?

Comment: looks like an out of bounds error... maybe you can try using [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/](`at`) function instead of `[]` operator. This one checks and throws an exception in such case. Then you know for sure you are out of bounds. BTW, you should put the function `opencv_tri`to understand what is wrong. Where do you do `frame = iMats[i]` ? I do not see it in your code

Comment: @api55 I have updated it, it is `iMats[i] = frame` and added link to `opencv_tri` function.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly I can't comment.
I think your vector is empty, therefor you can not access the [i]'th element.

```
vector<Mat> iMats(capture_source.size());
```

This creates an empty Vector with capture_source.size() elements.

Comment: Oops, I did `iMats.push_back(frame)` in the code but the issue is not with that. It isn't streaming continuously and I have to press `Esc` key to show frames and triangulation.

Answer (score 0):

I did not go through the whole opencv_tri function that you linked, but I spot the possible error.

you have the following

```
for(int i = 0;i<imats.size();i+=2)
{
```

...

```
 Mat imgATest = imats[i];
 Mat imgBTest = imats[i+1];
```

when `i` is in `imats.size()-1` it will try to access:

```
Mat imgBTest = imats[i+1];
```

This is an out of bounds. since i+1 is `imats.size()`

You have to loop up to `imats.size()-1`

```
for(int i = 0;i<imats.size()-1;i+=2)
{
```

this way it will not try to access the wrong value

Comment: in this case `imats.size()` value is `2` and I am doing `i+=2` so there's no way I can get `out of bounds error`.  **That's not causing the error.**

Comment: Nevertheless **that is an error**. You should try to use a debugger to at least know the exact line that gives error. This way it is easier to spot the what could be wrong. I am almost sure it is inside the `opencv_tri` function. Try going line by line with the debugger until it fails.